# Prove if $\log_{\frac{10}{9}}n = \Theta(\log_2n)$

Tags: functions, proof-explanation, asymptotics

I was reading *Quick Sort* in *Introduction to Algorithms, Third Edition*. There I came upon a line that states

> Notice that every level of the tree has cost $cn$, until the recursion reaches a boundary condition at depth $\log_{10} n =  \Theta(\lg n)$, and then the levels have cost at most $cn$. The recursion terminates at depth $\log_{\frac{10}{9}} n =  \Theta(\lg n)$

Here $\lg n$ stands for $\log_2 n$.

I think **that this is wrong**. **$\log_2 n$ is not an upper bound for $\log_{\frac{10}{9}} n$**. I plotted both the graphs and $\log_2 n$ does go above the curve of $\log_{\frac{10}{9}} n$ at any point.

[image]

#### Doubt

1. Where am I going wrong? Is my current understanding of *asymptotic functions* fundamentally wrong is someway?

Comment: The $\Theta$ notation means they are within a constant factor of each other, not that there is a strict inequality. Ie. $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$ if $C_1f(n)\leq g(n)\leq C_2 f(n)$ for some positive constants $C$.

Comment: Do you know that $\log_a n=( \log_a b)( \log_b n)$? Apply this with $a=10/9$ and $b=2$, then also with $a=2$ and $b=10/9$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\log_{10/9} (n) = {\log_2 (n) \over \log_2(10/9)}$.  Since we are multiplying by a constant, $\log_{10/9} (n) = \Theta(\log_2 (n))$.

Comment: I should have thought about this. I think I got too lost in the graph and forgot that we could choose constants.

Answer (score 1):

By a simple rule of logarithms, log$_\frac{10}{9}(x)$ is about log$_\frac{10}{9}(2)$ log$_2(x)$. Thus proved.